# Routing error when opening authenticated root when not signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm running into a strange issue with my Rails 6 app.  I'm using devise for two different models and have each scoped appropriately (I believe).  I have an `authenticated_root` path set up in my devise scope:

```
  devise_scope :tenant do
    authenticated :tenant do
      namespace :tenants do
        get 'home/my_key', as: :authenticated_root
        get 'home/guest_pass_list'
      end
    end
  end
```

In the controller:

```
class Tenants::HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_tenant!, only: %i[my_key, guest_pass_list]
```

This works perfectly fine when the tenant follows the typical sign in path, but when a user tries do open `/tenants/home/my_key` directly when not signed in, a routing error is thrown.  It seems like it should instead, redirect to the `tenants/sign_in` path.

What am I missing here? This has to be a configuration issue on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to define the `namespace :tenants` *outside* the `authenticated :tenant` block, because the `authenticated` macro defines the routes only for "authenticated" accounts. So, for an "unauthenticated" account, the route doesn't exist and it throws a routing exception.

More info: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-resource-actions-that-require-authentication-using-routes.rb

The redirect will be handled by the `before_action :authenticate_tenant!` callback in your controller. By the way, you should also change `%i[my_key, guest_pass_list]` to `%i[my_key guest_pass_list]` (note the `,` removal):

```rb
>> %i[my_key, guest_pass_list]
=> [:"my_key,", :guest_pass_list]
>> %i[my_key guest_pass_list]
=> [:my_key, :guest_pass_list]
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the answer.  Surprised I didn't come across that wiki when searching